# Extract values from API source (nested dictionary)

Tags: python, pandas, api, dictionary

I'm trying to extract only the dates and the cotton values in a dataframe. My attempts with pd.json_normalize / pd.DataFrame.from_dict did not work...

**Exemple :**

```
 {'data': {'success': True,
  'timeseries': True,
  'start_date': '2021-06-01',
  'end_date': '2022-05-01',
  'base': 'USD',
  'rates': {'2021-09-22': {'USD': 1, 'COTTON': 1.0994505494505},
   '2021-09-23': {'USD': 1, 'COTTON': 1.0876304347826},
   '2021-09-24': {'USD': 1, 'COTTON': 1.0877934782609},
   '2021-09-25': {'USD': 1},
   '2021-09-26': {'USD': 1, 'COTTON': 1.0876304347826},
   '2021-09-27': {'USD': 1, 'COTTON': 1.0874347826087},
...
   '2022-05-01': {'USD': 1, 'COTTON': 0.64516129032258}},
  'unit': 'per lb'}}
```

**Expected result :**

| Date | Cotton_Prices |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-23 | 1.0876304347826 |
| 2021-09-24 | 1.0877934782609 |
| ... | ... |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [[key, value.get('COTTON')] for key,value in response['data']['rates'].items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Cotton_prices'])
```

Result:

| Date | Cotton_prices |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-22 | 1.09945 |
| 2021-09-23 | 1.08763 |
| 2021-09-24 | 1.08779 |
| 2021-09-25 | nan |
| 2021-09-26 | 1.08763 |
| 2021-09-27 | 1.08743 |
| 2022-05-01 | 0.645161 |

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to parse your api response:

```
def response_to_df(response):
    column = {'date':[], 'cotton':[]}
    for date, rate in dic['data']['rates'].items():
        column['date'].append(date)
        column['cotton'].append(rate['COTTON'])
    return pd.DataFrame(column)
```